# Show Loading animation while trying to connect the server

Tags: c#, multithreading, function

I have a simple login form which connects to a server.

When the user presses the Login button, the animated Loading GIF needs to show until either the connection is made or it fails.

In theory, I did it:

```
private void button_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        button_login.Text = WORKING;
        Loading(ShowMode.show, pictureBox_login_loading);
        // send request         
        client = new TcpClient();
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5000);
            client.Connect(endPoint);
            // send login details .. :)
            output = client.GetStream();
            writer = new BinaryWriter(output);
            reader = new BinaryReader(output);
            // write details
            writer.Write("login"   "|"   userID   "|"   privateName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Server is down.");
            return;

        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop loading and return status
            button_login.Text = DEFAULT_LOGIN_TEXT;
            Loading(ShowMode.hide, pictureBox_login_loading);
        } 
}
```

Loading is a function that sets the PictureBox's Visible property to `Visible`. (I thought it would help)

The problem is: the gif is visible only after `button_login_Click` finishes its run, and right after it's invisible.

How do I make the animation gif visible right on the line it's executing?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not yielding back to the GUI thread, so there is no ability to display your GIF.

I would recommend using a BackgroundWorker to connect to your client, then displaying the GIF before starting the working and stopping it in the Worker's completed call.

Sample code (note, I didn't compile this because I don't have enough of your source to do so):

```
       button_login.Text = WORKING;
        Loading(ShowMode.show, pictureBox_login_loading);
        // send request      
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((obj, args) =>
        {
            client = new TcpClient();
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5000);
                client.Connect(endPoint);
                // send login details .. :)
                output = client.GetStream();
                writer = new BinaryWriter(output);
                reader = new BinaryReader(output);
                // write details
                writer.Write("login"   "|"   userID   "|"   privateName);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(() =>MessageBox.Show("Server is down."));
            }
        });

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler((obj, args) =>
        {
            button_login.Text = DEFAULT_LOGIN_TEXT;
            Loading(ShowMode.hide, pictureBox_login,loading);
        });

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

This approach yields to the GUI thread allowing it to display your GIF and still monitors your connection and removes the GIF and restore button text when done.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an animation you're after, you will probably need to initiate the connection on another thread so that the UI thread is not blocked. If it were a still image, you could just call the `Update()` method of the picturebox to get it to show. But for your case, something like this should work:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
{
    Invoke((Action)(()=>{ button_login.Text = WORKING; Loading(ShowMode.show, pictureBox_login_loading); }));
    // send request         
    client = new TcpClient();
    try
    {
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5000);
        client.Connect(endPoint);
        // send login details .. :)
        output = client.GetStream();
        writer = new BinaryWriter(output);
        reader = new BinaryReader(output);
        // write details
        writer.Write("login"   "|"   userID   "|"   privateName);
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Server is down.");
         return;

     }
     finally
     {
         // Stop loading and return status
         Invoke((Action)(()=>{ button_login.Text = DEFAULT_LOGIN_TEXT; Loading(ShowMode.hide, pictureBox_login_loading); }));
      } 
}));
thread.Start();
```

You could also use a BackgroundWorker like the other answer discussed, but I tend to reserve them for longer running tasks, such as ones that report progress with a progress bar. If it is a short(ish) task, I usually use a `Thread`, or `Task.Factory.StartNew` in .NET 4.0.